# AS3 AIR / FlashBuilder How to release socket on exit?

Tags: actionscript-3, sockets, flash-builder

When I exit from the debugger and relaunch I often get the message:

```
Error: Error #2002: Operation attempted on invalid socket.
    at flash.net::ServerSocket/internalBind()
    at flash.net::ServerSocket/bind()
```

I usually have to wait a while before I can relaunch the application without the error.

How can I avoid this?

```
private function openConnection():void
    {
        _serverSocket = new ServerSocket();
        _serverSocket.addEventListener(ServerSocketConnectEvent.CONNECT, onConnect)
        _serverSocket.bind(888);
        _serverSocket.listen();
    }

    private function onConnect(e:ServerSocketConnectEvent):void
    {
        trace("Client is connected");
        _clientSocket = e.socket;
        _clientSocket.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA, onData);
        _clientSocket.addEventListener(Event.CLOSE, onConnectionClosed);
    }
```

Comment: Closing the window will close the socket. Your server might be hanging on to the port, but that still shouldn't matter. Post your AS3 code.

Comment: Are you calling for a policy file?

Comment: No I'm not calling a policy file. Is this necessary for two AIR applications on a local network?

Comment: Local network is not local machine so yeah you should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can avoid it. I it just takes awhile for the OS to free the socket after AIR lets go of it. As a workaround, you could catch the error and use a timer to retry binding the socket every few seconds.

And AIR apps never need policy files (unless the code opening the socket was loaded from outside the application).